# Jquery slide toggle. Reset css back to dafault

Tags: jquery, slide, slidetoggle

I'm using a toggle function on a button to show and hide a div containing a youtube video. The video is a sign language video that translates the content on the page.

However, I'm also using the same button to reduce the site container div but 50% and remove the margin to allow space for both the video and the site content.

This all works really well, however when I click the button to hide the video again, only the video is hidden and the remaining css does not revert back to it default.

Im a little new to jQuery and I'm sure there are some simpler ways to achieve what I'm doing here. But I basically need everything to revert back to default on the closing click.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#bslvideoshow").click(function() {
    jQuery("#bslvideo").slideToggle("swing");
    jQuery(".container").css("width", "50%");
    jQuery(".container").css("margin", "0");
    jQuery(".content-navigation").css("display", "none");  
    jQuery("#sidebar-toggle").css("display", "block");
    jQuery("#sidebar-toggle").css("width", "50%");
    jQuery("#sidebar-toggle").css("float", "none");
    jQuery(".sidebar").css("width", "50%");
    jQuery(".sidebar .container").css("width", "100%");
    jQuery(".menu-item-389").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#search").css("float", "none");
    jQuery("#search-field").css("width", "97%");
    jQuery(".top-bg-white").css("width", "50%");
    jQuery(".call-to-action").css("right","50%");
    jQuery(".sub-menu .attachment-full").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

Comment: You should toggle a class when it comes to just set/reset some style

Comment: Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: Set CSS rules for specific elements and class, use toggleClass('myClass') to add/remove specific style.